# iOS - is it possible to get background image set by iPhone user?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to know (access) which image is set as the phone background? I want to put the same image in a UIImageView in my app.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible to programmatically get the home screen or lock screen wallpaper image. You should ask the user to select the background image from their photo library.

Comment: Maybe that's the reason I haven't found anything. Thank you!

Comment: iOS apps are sandboxed which means access to system-level resources & settings are heavily controlled by Apple. Even those that Apple expose need permission granted by the user before the app can access them.